# Binding same class and event to multiple dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleClass">Show/Hide</a><br>
<li :class="{myClass: showItems}">Item 1</li>

<a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleClass">Show/Hide</a><br>
<li :class="{myClass: showItems}">Item 2</li>

<a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleClass">Show/Hide</a>
<li :class="{myClass: showItems}">Item 3</li>
```

And the JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showItems: true
  },
  methods: {
    toggleClass: function(){
      this.showItems = !this.showItems;
    }
  }
});
```

When I click on any one of the `<a>` elements, the `toggleClass()` method gets executed which sets the `showItems` to either `true` or `false` which eventually gets applied to all of the elements. and because the `<li>` elements are dynamically generated through a php foreach loop, I have no manual control over the class name of the element.

Within the for loop, the HTML structure might look something like this:

```
foreach($items as $item):
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleClass">Show/Hide</a><br>
    <li :class="{myClass: showItems}">Item $item</li>
endforeach
```

How do I deal with this situation? Here is a [JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/petudasuge/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: in your demo thre is no the foreach...

Comment: That's because foreach is a php construct and the place where I uploaded the code, supports javascript only.

Comment: mm, then you need to make it under Vue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not good: *generating `<li>` by php*.

You should pass $items as json to client then  render them via `v-for`

**html:**

```
<script>
    window.vueData = {items: <?php echo json_encode($items) ?>}
</script>
<ul>
    <li v-for="(item,index) in items">
        <span :class="{myClass: showItems[index]}">item {{ item }}<span>
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="showItems[index] = !showItems[index]">Show/Hide</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**js**

```
  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: window.vueData.items,
    showItems: window.vueData.items.map(() => {return true;}),
  }
});
```

Comment: `showItems: window.items.map(() => {return true;}),` is it `window.items.map()` or `this.items.map()`?

Comment: That was my mistake! correct code is: `window.vueData.items.map(() => {return true;})`.

Answer (score 0):

is only a demo of the idea, if you are using an array of items everyone need to have custom "showItems" so this is a demo code( not testd, based in yours):

```
foreach($items as $item):
    <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleClass($item)">Show/Hide</a><br>
    <li :class="{myClass: $item.showItems}">Item $item</li>

endforeach
```

And in the methos toggle:

```
methods: {
    toggleClass: function(item){
      item.showItems = !item.showItems;
    }
  }
```

Sure, is different under Vue, and this code not work fine, but give you a idea of would it happens

Comment: I could not understand this part: `item.showItems = !item.showItems;`, I access the `showItems` property using `this.showItems` because it is a data property. Why are you calling it on `item`? `item` doesn't have a property called `showItems`

Comment: is custom object item property

Comment: But aren't you passing it through `toggleClass($item)`? Here, `$item` came from the for loop, how can this be custom?

Comment: We are directly passing the `$item` variable to the method `toggleClass`, we never assigned `showItems` property to item. `showItems` is still in the data property

Comment: as i see your code, you need to create create a component for each element of the array that's idea of use vue and components